# Converting a graph with custom nodes and edges to Dot format using Graph for Scala

Tags: scala, graph

I created a simple graph with custom nodes and edges as follows:

```
case class Agent(val name: String) {
   override def toString = name // without Airport-prefix
}

class Ask[N](nodes: Product, val message: String, val msgNo: String) 
    extends DiEdge[N](nodes)
    with    ExtendedKey[N]
    with    EdgeCopy[Ask]
    with    OuterEdge[N,Ask] {

  def mesage = message
  def keyAttributes = Seq(msgNo)
  override def copy[NN](newNodes: Product) =
    new Ask[NN](newNodes,message, msgNo)
}

object Ask {
  def apply(src: Agent, dst: Agent, message:String, msgNo: String) =
    new Ask[Agent](NodeProduct(src, dst), message, msgNo)

  def unapply(e: Ask[Agent]) = Some(e)
}


implicit class AskAssoc[A <: Agent](val e: LDiEdge[A]) {
  @inline def ## (message: String, msgNo: String) =
    new Ask[A](e.nodes, message,msgNo) //with OuterEdge[A,Ask]
}

val (ham, ny) = (Agent("HAM"), Agent("JFK")) // two nodes
val g = Graph[Agent,Ask](((ham ~+> ny) ("Ask") ) ## ("messgae", "kfree"))
```

All of it works fine. Now, I want to convert g to DOT format.

I start with defining root as follows:

```
val root = DotRootGraph(directed = true,
 id       = Some("Wikipedia_Example"))
```

But the I am unable to get around the EdgeTransformer. I think #EdgeT is not the right way of extracting innerEdge from the custom graph. Can you please help me with this?

```
def edgeTransformer(innerEdge: Graph[Agent,Ask]#EdgeT):
        Option[(DotGraph,DotEdgeStmt)] = innerEdge.edge match {
            case LDiEdge(source, target,label) => source match {
                 case label: Agent =>
                  Some((root,
                          DotEdgeStmt(source.toString,
                                              target.toString,
                                              if (label.nonEmpty) List(DotAttr("label", label.toString))
                                             else                Nil)))                                                                                              
       }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution!

The edge transformer needs to match against Ask, not LDiEdge. To do so, first implement Ask's unapply like

def unapply[N](e: Ask[N]): Option[(N,N,String,String)] = Some((e._1, e._2, e.message, e.msgNo))

Then you may match against the pattern

case Ask(source, target, message, msgNo) =>

That's all I was missing!